# mewp openid provider configuration

Tags: openid, provider

I set up [Mewp-s provider](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/trees/master/provider), but as i would to authenticate myself in stackoverflow i get this:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID
>   provider:
>
> Error occurred while sending a direct
>   message or getting the response

What could be the problem?

Comment: Such a generic question... there could be many problems. What example are you using? When does it fail? (after, or before authentication) Does it work with LightOpenID?

Comment: I use the two php-s on above link.  I try log in with http://<my-site.com>/provider-example.php to stackoverflow, i am befor authentication.

Comment: I tried it with lightopenid. After i filled the form, i get the answer "Endless redirection!". I changed nothing neither in provider nor in consumer.

Comment: With my gmail openid lightopenid works great.

Comment: Ok, so I have identified a bug with LightOpenID that prevented it to work with it's provider, but I still have no idea why would stackoverflow not. It works for me, so I can't really debug it myself. Download the newest version, try to authenticate, and then check if you have file "log" in the directory with provider.php. If you do, mail me it's contents (or paste it to pastebin.com). If you don't and still have this problem, could you mail me the address to your site (if you don't want to publish it here), so that I can test what might be wrong myself?.

Comment: I sent you an mail. It was something problemn with $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] was not received. So i tried an other browser. Normally i use safari, but now i tried with firefox this authentication process on stackoverflow. Now, I get the authentication window, but test/test was not accepted. After it i come back to safari, and now the authentication window appear, and test/test was accepted. Strange.

Comment: In stackoverflow first time i get autentication window and after test/test i get the error, and after it, as i try it again, i can get through. LightOpenID still work not.

Comment: There was a bug within lightopenid that caused it not to work with the provider. It was fixed before my previous comment, so you shouldn't have problems now. Download it from [here](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/raw/master/openid.php).

Comment: Perfect, it works :-D Can you help me still a little bit? So i would to save the identity of visitors. In openid.php which row i should to insert this command, and in which variable is it? Other question: does your algoritm retrieve the url of photo, if the provider send it? I think it could be usefull. For example, i could put a tha small visitors  photo aside my blog. As this facebook stuff like.

Comment: Look at the example, and you'll see that the identifier is in `$openid->identity`. As for the photo, you can request `media/image/default`, but I most OPs don't support it. However, you could request `contact/email`, and then use gravatar.com to fetch avatars -- you can also request identicons (like your avatar on SO) if the avatar isn't avaiable there.

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?